# Null error when setting class variable in array

Tags: c#

i'm coding the game of life in c# and keep getting a null error when trying to set a class variable in an array.

```
class Program
    {
        public class cell
        {
            public int x = Console.LargestWindowWidth + 1;
            public int y = Console.LargestWindowHeight + 1;
            public bool alive;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int winWidth = Console.LargestWindowWidth;
            int winHeight = Console.LargestWindowHeight;
            cell[] currentgeneration = new cell[Console.LargestWindowWidth * Console.LargestWindowHeight];

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            foreach (var item in currentgeneration)
            {
                if (x == winWidth++)
                {
                    y++;
                    x = 0;
                }
                item.x = x;
                item.y = y;
                x++;
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please [edit] your question to include full details of the error you're seeing: what the exact message is, and which line it appears on.

Comment: in which line you get error ?! and add the text of your error to question.

Comment: You are getting the error because the array has only null values. You have not create "new cell" in the array... All you did was create an array with a bunch of null values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate all of the objects in your array first, before you use them in the foreach:

```
for (int count = 0; count < currentgeneration.Count(); count++)
    currentgeneration[count] = new cell();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you initialize currentgeneration array with null values. Then you are accessing properties on null objects. In your iteration item is always null

Answer (score 0):

Your item has no value. `currentgeneration` is a Array which only contains `null` values. So you cannot set x or y on null.

Answer (score 0):

You've created the *array*

```
// array of null's 
cell[] currentgeneration = 
  new cell[Console.LargestWindowWidth * Console.LargestWindowHeight];
```

but you haven't create items *instances*, i.e. you want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentgeneration.Length; ++i)
  cell[i] = new cell() {
    y     = i / Console.LargestWindowWidth,
    x     = i % Console.LargestWindowWidth,
    alive = true, //TODO: put the right value here 
  };
```

you can do it (creating array and its items) in one go with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

cell[] currentgeneration = Enumerable
  .Range(0, Console.LargestWindowWidth * Console.LargestWindowHeight) 
  .Select(index => new cell() {
     y     = index / Console.LargestWindowWidth,
     x     = index % Console.LargestWindowWidth,
     alive = true, //TODO: put the right value here 
   })
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

currentgeneration is an array you have created but you have not assigned any values in the array